# ignoring timestamp in WHERE clause when comparing to date

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

My table has records like these

`23-MAY-11 11.40.39.000000 AM`

The following query brings nothing

```
SELECT * 
  FROM my_table 
 WHERE tenant_pha = 'test'
   AND create_date >= TO_DATE('05/10/2011','mm/dd/yyyy')
   AND create_date <= TO_DATE('05/23/2011','mm/dd/yyyy')
```

However, the below query will bring data

```
SELECT * 
  FROM my_table 
 WHERE tenant_pha = 'test'
   AND create_date >= TO_DATE('05/10/2011','mm/dd/yyyy')
   AND create_date <= TO_DATE('05/24/2011','mm/dd/yyyy')
```

I think this is because `create_date` column is time stamp.

How can I change my query to bring the desired result ( I want to avoid doing functions on the left side columns because they will make the query long).

Comment: Post the `CREATE TABLE` statement.  Are you sure data exists that has a date between the ones specified **and** the `tenant_pha` equals "test"?

Comment: yeah i've verified that the data exists.

Comment: I'm struggling to see the difference between the two queries - can you highlight it somehow?

Comment: typo on my part. second one should have been `05/24/2011` that way it covers all day of 23rd (updated).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right about the timestamp.  '05/23/2011' is the same as '05/23/2011 12:00 AM'.

To include the whole day I usually move my date up by a day.  < '05/24/2011' will include all of 5/23.

or change to '05/23/2011 23:59:59'

Comment: great, was just about to do that but wanted assurance that its the standard way to go :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use trunc() without problems, you only need to create a function based index.

If you create this index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_trunc_date ON my_table (trunc(create_date));
```

then the following condition will make use of that index:

```
AND trunc(create_date) >= TO_DATE('05/10/2011','mm/dd/yyyy')
```

Comment: not allowed to change/create indexes in this hell hole without a 2 hour meeting.